Windows CPP compiler ignore specific warnings and treat every warning as error
I am following this documentation
I want to treat all warnings as error and ignore these specific warnings but I get an error:
set _CL_="-WX -WD28020 -WD28112 -WD28132 -WD28159 -WD28182 -WD28195 -WD28196 -WD28197 -WD28204 -WD28213 -WD28218 -WD28251 -WD28252 -WD28253 -WD28285 -WD28301 -WD28649 -WD28716 -WD28719 -WD6001 -WD6011 -WD6031 -WD6054 -WD6101 -WD6221 -WD6226 -WD6239 -WD6244 -WD6255 -WD6258 -WD6262 -WD6276 -WD6287 -WD6294 -WD6313 -WD6314 -WD6326 -WD6336 -WD6340 -WD6385 -WD6387 -WD6388 -WD6506 -WD6518 -WD6553 -WDA1416 -WDA2200 -WDR64 -WD0436 -WD0618 -WD0649 -WD3003"

Error saying invalid numeric argument:
cl : Command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/WX -WD28020 -WD28112 -WD28132 -WD28159 -WD28182 -WD28195 -WD28196 -WD28197 -WD28204 -WD28213 -WD28218 -WD28251 -WD28252 -WD28253 -WD28285 -WD28301 -WD28649 -WD28716 -WD28719 -WD6001 -WD6011 -WD6031 -WD6054 -WD6101 -WD6221 -WD6226 -WD6239 -WD6244 -WD6255 -WD6258 -WD6262 -WD6276 -WD6287 -WD6294 -WD6313 -WD6314 -WD6326 -WD6336 -WD6340 -WD6385 -WD6387 -WD6388 -WD6506 -WD6518 -WD6553 -WDA1416 -WDA2200 -WDR64 -WD0436 -WD0618 -WD0649 -WD3003' [C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\ktl\src\tools\tests\KernelLib\KmUnitKernel.vcxproj]
cl : Command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/WX -WD28020 -WD28112 -WD28132 -WD28159 -WD28182 -WD28195 -WD28196 -WD28197 -WD28204 -WD28213 -WD28218 -WD28251 -WD28252 -WD28253 -WD28285 -WD28301 -WD28649 -WD28716 -WD28719 -WD6001 -WD6011 -WD6031 -WD6054 -WD6101 -WD6221 -WD6226 -WD6239 -WD6244 -WD6255 -WD6258 -WD6262 -WD6276 -WD6287 -WD6294 -WD6313 -WD6314 -WD6326 -WD6336 -WD6340 -WD6385 -WD6387 -WD6388 -WD6506 -WD6518 -WD6553 -WDA1416 -WDA2200 -WDR64 -WD0436 -WD0618 -WD0649 -WD3003' [C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\src\Reliability\ROS-api\interfacing\lib\ROSInterfacingLib.vcxproj]
cl : Command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/WX -WD28020 -WD28112 -WD28132 -WD28159 -WD28182 -WD28195 -WD28196 -WD28197 -WD28204 -WD28213 -WD28218 -WD28251 -WD28252 -WD28253 -WD28285 -WD28301 -WD28649 -WD28716 -WD28719 -WD6001 -WD6011 -WD6031 -WD6054 -WD6101 -WD6221 -WD6226 -WD6239 -WD6244 -WD6255 -WD6258 -WD6262 -WD6276 -WD6287 -WD6294 -WD6313 -WD6314 -WD6326 -WD6336 -WD6340 -WD6385 -WD6387 -WD6388 -WD6506 -WD6518 -WD6553 -WDA1416 -WDA2200 -WDR64 -WD0436 -WD0618 -WD0649 -WD3003' [C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\src\Reliability\ROSService\lib\ROSServiceLib.vcxproj]
C:\.tools\CxCache\Wix.Corext.3.14.0.1119\wix2010.targets(1025,5): error MSB4181: The "MSBuild" task returned false but did not log an error.


What is your question about that?

I'm not sure how you are following the documentation that you've linked. It doesn't mention any -WD... options.

@mkrieger1 what is wrong with my -WX*? that is my question.

If you have Visual Studio, you can go to the Project Settings dialog, enter all of this information, and then go to the Command-Line option in the project settings to see what the command-line would look like.  Basically there is no need to guess this if you have the Visual Studio IDE.

@mkrieger1 using _CL_ is a proper way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/cl-environment-variables?view=msvc-170

Don't use ", according to that link. It's trying to treat the entire thing as one argument. Also, options in VS are /WX /wd28929 (etc). I'd question what you're doing though. If you're using VS, then add the options through the VS IDE, it's simpler.

What mkrieger1 hints at is that per documentation, there is no /WD... options, only /wd... ones (note the case). And PaulMcKenzie says that you wouldn't commit such a mistake if you were using the Project's Properties dialog first to compose the command line (for later use in the _CL_ environment variable).

/wd"4800" /wd"4714"  -- That is a sample I just got by using the Visual Studio IDE if I want to disable warnings 4800 and 4714.   Go to the main menu  Project Settings -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line.  Of course, I used VS to list the warnings to ignore (a semicolon delimited string, 4800;4714 ) in the C/C++ -> Advanced section of the project properties.

@Node.JS Also, the only time I needed to actually look at the documentation for the command-line as you did is if there is an option that is not available in the Project Settings dialog.  Most, if not all of these options are available in the configuration properties dialog anyway.

Side note:  There are many compilers for Windows operating system.  In your next post, please indicate the compiler you are using.

The cl part of Visual Studio generally uses 4 digit error codes. I suspect that the 5-digit codes are from IntelliSense, and that is why CL doesn't like them.
